# Java - see if a list module contains a certain value

Tags: java, swing

Let's say I have this:

```
public DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
```

how do i make it so I can see if it contains a certain string?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the [`contains()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) method.

```
model.contains("MyString");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `contains()`